# NOT condition in 'if case' statement

Tags: swift

I have an enum:

```
enum E {
    case A, B, C(Int)
}

let a: E = .A
```

Here's how I would check if `a` equals `.B`

```
if case .B = a {
    // works fine
}
```

But how do I check the opposite condition? (`a` **not** equal `.B`)? Here's what I tried:

```
if case .B != a { // Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
    // ...
}

if !(case .B = a) { // Expected ',' separator
    // ...
}
```

Of course, I could do it this way:

```
if case .B = a {
    // ...
} else {
    // put your code here
}
```

but this is awkward, as well as using `switch` statement. Are there any better options?

---

**EDIT:** The solution @Greg suggested works if cases do not have associated values, but if they do `==` operator needs to be overloaded. Sorry for not clarifying this in the first place.

Comment: if !(case .B = a) { // Expected ',' separator. -- It should be double == not single one.

Comment: @Greg, nope, same error

Comment: I ran in similar situation and ended up making function for checking that and returning Bool. That made it easier.

Answer (score 39):

This "answer" is nothing more than writing your *awkward* solution in a more compact manner.  If you only care about the case when a value is not of a certain enum value, you could write it like this all in one line with the `else` immediately following the empty then clause:

```
enum E {
    case A, B(String), C(Int)
}

let a: E = .B("Hello")

if case .A = a {} else {
    print("not an A")
}

if case .B = a {} else {
    print("not a B")
}

if case .C = a {} else {
    print("not a C")
}
```

Comment: Somebody who reads this code might not notice the `{} else` part, but yeah, otherwise it's a viable solution :)

Comment: @AndriiChernenko Considering that Swift's `guard` keyword _requires_ the use of `else`, I think this could would be grokkable by the average Swift programmer.

Answer (score 13):

There aren't any answers yet mentioning the `guard` statement, introduced by Swift 2, which is a neat addition to the tools above and, if you ask me, the cleanest solution if you can live with the requirement to `return` from your function or closure within the `else`-block:

```
guard case .B = a else {
    // a does not match .B
    return
}
```

See [Apple's "The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2): Statements"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/guard-statement) for more info.

Comment: If this is truly an invalid case then guard is acceptible. However if this is just a part of the flow to execute certain functionality guard would be misplaced here I think. What do you think?

Comment: The Swift compiler will yell at you if you try to "fall through" the guard clause: `'guard' body may not fall through, consider using 'return' or 'break' to exit the scope`. I think "guarding" sounds less negative than "invalidating", which, if you approach them from a neutral perspective, might allow you to use `guard`-clauses for a lot more cases than just preventing catastrophy :)

Comment: It's good to know that the compiler prevents misuse of the guard clause (fall through). My project is still in it's baby steps and I have only used guard to actually catch the situations I don't allow. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You are using single = sign which is an assignment operator. You have to use double == which is a comparison one and don't use case .A, use E.A is the right way to do that:

```
if E.A == a {
    // works fine
    print("1111")
}

if E.B != a {
    // works fine
    print("2222")
}

if E.B == a {
    // works fine
    print("3333")
}
```

Extended:

To make it works with associated values you have to implement Equatable protocol, example:

```
extension E: Equatable {}
func ==(lhs: E, rhs: E) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (let .C(x1), let .C(x2)):
            return x1 == x2
        case (.A, .A):
        return true

     default:
         return false
    }
}
```

Of course you have to handle all of the possibilities but I think you have an idea.

Extended:

I don't get your comment but this works for me fine:

```
enum E {
    case A, B, C(Int)
}

extension E: Equatable {}
func ==(lhs: E, rhs: E) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (let .C(x1), let .C(x2)):
            return x1 == x2
        case (.A, .A):
            return true
        case (.B, .B):
            return true

     default:
         return false
    }
}

let a: E = .A
let b: E = .B
let c: E = .C(11)

if E.A == a {
    // works fine
    print("aaa true")
}
if E.A != a {
    // works fine
    print("aaa false")
}

if E.B == b {
    // works fine
    print("bbb true")
}

if E.B == b {
    // works fine
    print("bbb false")
}

if E.C(11) == c {
    // works fine
    print("ccc true")
}

if E.C(11) != c {
    // works fine
    print("1 ccc false")
}

if E.C(22) != c {
    // works fine
    print("2 ccc false")
}
```

Comment: true, it works, but not if cases have associated values. sorry for not claryfing this.

Comment: @deville see extended answer.

Comment: if I overload `==` it will work for `.A` and `.B`, but not for `.C`, which has associated value. That's why pattern matching is needed.

Comment: @deville sorry I don't understand. When you implement Equatable as explained in answer you can use == with any case. Have a look on my switch (with pattern matching) I only give you an example with .A & .A and .C & .C but you can and you should test any possibility. You said that it won't work with .C but my example works with .C

Comment: I mean I cannot just write `if .C == a {}`, it has to be `if .C(0) == a {}`, which obviously will not work if `a` contains `.C(1)`. Pattern matching covers this use case: `if case .C = a {}` will be true if `a` contains `.C` with *any* associated value.

Comment: @deville copy and paste my last bit of code from the answer to the playground and see that all just works fine.

Comment: No disagreement, it does, but `if E.C != c` will not work. And sometimes I need to check if the value of `c` is `.C`, not caring about the associated value.

Comment: @deville with your question you have .C(Int) with means that the associated value must be provided. Compiler won't let you create .C case with no value: let c: E = .C <- Compiler time error. Show me an example what doesn't work for you and I'm happy to have a look on it for you tomorrow.

Comment: As I mentioned before, pattern matching allows me to test if variable contains `.C` with **ANY** associated value (not some specific one like `0`, `1`, `22` or whatever). And the compiler is perfectly fine with `if case .C = c {}`.
This is the only case `==` operator overloading, on which you insist, does not address. That is why such solution is not universal.

Answer (score -1):

I saw the guard answer, and I though I could improve upon it.

Note how the `do` block is named. <sub><sup>I mean, it works</sup></sub>

```swift
i: do { guard case .B = a else {
    print("foo")
break i }}
```

Granted, this is much smaller: `if case .B = a {} else { *** }`

---

You can use this if you really want that `!` operator

```swift
func cases<T: Equatable>(_ a: T,_ b: T) -> Bool { return a == b }
if cases(.B, a) {}
if !cases(.B, a) {}
```

Comment: `return a == b` is wrong. What if `case` has `associated value`s?!

Comment: @Farid I forgot to mention you have to add `extension E: Equatable {}` Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Still wrong. How are you supposed to check if `a` and `b` has same `associated value`s?

Answer (score -6):

Negating the .case statement is not possible. However you can use a normal comparison, like this:

```
if a != .B {

}
```

This is the most direct way to write it, in my opinion.

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only if `.B` does not have associated values.

Comment: @AndriiChernenko Thank you for letting me know. I will keep the answer, so other developers can learn from my mistake.