# Alternative to case Swift

Tags: swift

Ive got an enum

```
enum Display {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
    case blank
}
```

and want to check if an element in my `[Display]` is blank.

I can do this with a switch case

```
switch element {
case .blank:
    print ("all is fine")
default:
    return
}
```

so if it isn't blank we return.

I'd prefer an if statement

```
if element != blank
```

But I can't seem to do this with an `Enum`. Surely there's a better way?

Comment: why not use your switch and write whatever you want in default rather than ! `switch element { case .blank: break default: //do whatever you want }`

Comment: Make the enum `Equatable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if case` for that. Read here: http://fuckingifcaseletsyntax.com

Copy paste from the website for you lazy guys out there:

```swift
if case let Puppy.mastiff(droolRating, weight) = fido {
... // tell fido he's a good boy
```

is equivalent to:

```swift
switch fido {
case let Puppy.mastiff(droolRating, weight):
... // tell fido he's a good boy
```

Comment: What is the syntax for != though? If not we're in the same situation with an if - then - else with nothing in the then.

Comment: read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676490/not-condition-in-if-case-statement or https://forums.swift.org/t/if-not-case/20085. Seems like this is a problem not solved as elegant as expected in swift :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to to this in several places in your code it might be worth adding a computed property to your enum to check `.blank`

```
var isBlank: Bool {
    get {
        if case Display.blank = self {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in a way that makes your other code cleaner

```
array.contains(where: {$0.isBlank})

element.isBlank
```